# How do I remove tiles from the Kobo home screen?

Tags: ebook-readers, kobo, kobo-glo

With the newest update to my Kobo Glo, instead of the old tiles where I could just long press on something and get an option to remove it, I can't seem to do that anymore.

There's this "Take a Quick Tour" image/button that now takes up almost 1/4 of my screen on my home screen - I don't need to take the tour! I've had this device for a long time.

I tried taking the tour to see if that would disappear after, and it didn't. I tried long pressing on it to see if that would let me remove it like I could with the tiles in the old update, no option comes up.

Is there any way to get rid of this? It's frustrating, and I don't need it.

Comment: Same problem kobo mini
kobo utilities does not have remove tiles anymore

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin for Calibre called [Kobo Utilities](https://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=215339) that can dismiss unwanted tiles from the Home screen.

> The Kobo Utilities Plugin adds extra function to calibre for working
>   with Kobo WiFi, Touch, Glo, Mini, Aura, Aura HD, Aura H2O and Glo HD
>   eReaders. This will allow changes on the eReaders that either cannot
>   otherwise be made or will make them easier to do.
>
> The current functions of the plugin are:
>
> - Set/Remove font settings for specific books.
> - **Dismiss tiles from tiled home screen.**
> - Update metadata directly to the database on the device.
> - Change the reading status.
> - Manage series info for books on the device. This is mainly for books not in the calibre library including kepubs.
> - Store/record current reading position for ePubs. This can be done manually or automatically when the Kobo ereader is connected. Profiles
>     can be used to manage the reading positions of multiple devices.
> - Upload/Remove covers for all books in the library. This includes kepubs.
> - A couple of annotations options that I'm not happy with.
> - List the books missing from the device database. This only lists the books that calibre thinks should be in the database.
> - Backup the device database.
> - Run integrity check on the database. It doesn't fix anything, but it tells you if the database is OK or not.
> - Clean up duplicate shelves.
> - Remove annotations files.
> - Set "Related books" for sideloaded books.

Comment: But it doesn't work with the newest firmware mentioned by the OP. See reply #39 here: https://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=284165&page=3

Comment: I wasn't aware of this. I still use the previous firmware version.

Comment: Yeah, as you can see from the linked thread, the new home screen has upset quite a few people. And it's not on all of the devices; Kobo is apparently doing A/B testing on the new layout. So if you don't like it, tell Kobo.

Comment: I still haven't had the chance to try it, I can't say if I like it or not :)

Comment: I suppose that comment was directed more toward the OP and anyone else who arrives here experiencing the same problem.